# Is Vivi's Peacock Slasher based on a real life weapon?

Tags: one-piece

Princess Vivi is a former member of Baroque Works with the code name Miss Wednesday.
She fights using her weapons, the Peacock Slasher.

Her weapons can easily cut off human heads, as we can see when she cut off Crocodile's head (even though it's because he is a sandman).

I want to know whether the Peacock Slasher is based on a real life weapon or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest I can think of is this [weapon](http://www.warrior-concepts-online.com/kyoketsu-shoge.html) used by ninjas.

[image: kyoketsu-shoge]

> The kyoketsu-shoge or rope-and-dagger weapon is one of the Ninja's
>   unique specialty weapons.

This should be the inspiration for *Peacock Slasher*.